# При передаче изображения неожиданно передается nil

Tags: ios

Функция завершается с сообщением  "**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**"

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

**//1   получаю view controller**
let destinationVC: SaveAfterFilterScreen = segue.destinationViewController 
as! SaveAfterFilterScreen

**// 2   передаю image не пустой, и тут приложение падает**

destinationVC.imageViewFinal.image = imageFromCamera.image!
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что передавать напрямую в UI объект нельзя в prepareForSegue:, так как его еще не существует. Следует передавать его сначала в переменную просто как UIImage, затем в viewDidLoad присваивать изображение из UIImage в UIImageView.

Comment: Точнее передавать можно, если UI уже создан. Для этого можно вызвать [destinationVC view]; или дождаться окончания загрузки. Или создать .imageViewFinal в коде, в методе initWith, но это уже не так хорошо. 
Лучше действительно передать картинку через переменную UIImage или вызвать метод view (чтоб загрузились все вьюшки).

Comment: @Валентин пофикшено

Answer (score 0):

Выведи в лог:

destinationVC

destinationVC.imageViewFinal

imageFromCamera

imageFromCamera.image

Сразу найдешь nil.